# Conditional style in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've made a style that makes `TextBlock` look like a link:

```
<Style x:Key="linkStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="navigateLink" />
</Style>
```

How to apply it only when `TextBlock.Text` starts with *http://* ?

Comment: You may be able to use a StyleSelector.  See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082509/wpf-use-a-styleselector-for-a-button

Comment: Probably you have to use events and custom C# code to do that; by default, XAML is not smart enough to emulate String.StartsWith or apply styles based on regular expressions. Of course, you also can create custom control that inherits TextBlock and has property like DoesTextStartWithHttp, so you will can use this property in XAML, however, for me it is easier to use event handlers to change style in C# code.

Comment: It's ok to use custom C# code (and it already has some, the `navigateLink` function) but I want to be able to apply resulting style to simple `TextBlock`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this

```
<Style x:Key="linkStyleConditional" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In SomeConverter write the logic if text start with http//: then return true else return false. i hope this will help.

Comment: that's very nice answer, just one thing.
how can I write SomeConverter in xaml with condition?