# Border is added only to the first text block in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Edit : I realized what the problem is, when I add the border, The second TextBlock sits on top of the first TextBlock. Still have to figure out why this is happening.

Original question:
I have a number of `TextBlock`s in my xaml. I want to add a border around some textblocks. I tried the following methods.

Method 1:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderForTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
     <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
     <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
</Style>


<TextBlock1../>
<Border Style="{StaticResource BorderForTextBlock}">
    <TextBlock2.../> 
</Border>
```

Method 2:

```
<TextBlock1../> //This is where the border is added.
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <TextBlock2 ..../>     //This is where I want to add the border
</Border>
```

A border is added only to the first TextBlock in the xaml no matter to which TextBlock I add the border. I don't want the border on the first TextBlock. I have no clue why this is happening.

This is my xaml :

```
<Grid Background="LightYellow" >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.5*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="28*" ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="120*"  ></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="28*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="74*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,5,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{x:Static res:Resources.source1"/>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock1" FormatTest:FormattedTextBehavior.FormattedText="{Binding Path= content1}"   Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Border>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  Margin="10,0,5,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{x:Static res:Resources.source2}"/>

<RichTextBox Background="LightYellow" Margin="0,0,0,0"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" IsReadOnly="True"  >
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="{Binding content2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>


<TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Margin="10,0,5,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{x:Static res:Resources.source3"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding content3, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3"   Margin="10,0,5,0" FontWeight="SemiBold" Text="{x:Static res:Resources.source4}"/>
<TextBox   Text="{Binding content4, Mode=TwoWay}"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="LightYellow" IsReadOnly="True"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: This works fine for me, how are you laying out textblocks ? or add more code

Comment: I'll add the code. Give me a minute.

Comment: I have added the code. Border is added only around the first textBlock. Not the second one.

Comment: how do you select few ?

Comment: @nanda A **TextBlock** element cannot display a border because it lacks **BorderBrush** and **BorderThickness** properties. If you want a border around a text block, place it within a **Border** element. The reason you are seeing borders around certain text blocks and not others is due to the layering of the items in your **Grid**.

Comment: @StevenRands That is what I have done. I have placed a Border around a text block. But when I do that, the position of the TextBlock changes. Why is that happening?

Comment: @Muds I have to put a border around some textblocks. When I do that, the position of those textblocks changes. It sits on top of the very first textblock in the xaml.

Comment: That is because you need to provide grid row col settings to border.. see code in my ans below

Comment: @nanda Setting the **BorderThickness** property of the **Border** element will adjust the _apparent_ position of the contained element. This effect is more pronounced the larger the thickness value. If you want the contained element to "stay where it is" and place a border on the _outside_ of it, then set the **Margin** property of the **Border** element to the negative of its **BorderThickness**. For example, if **BorderThickness** is set to 1, then set the **Margin** to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock1" FormatTest:FormattedTextBehavior.FormattedText="{Binding Path= content1}"   Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Border>
```

Have

```
<Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock1" FormatTest:FormattedTextBehavior.FormattedText="{Binding Path= content1}"   Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Border>
```

This should solve the issue with placement of text blocks

This is how it looks  at my end[image]

Try this and let us know

Comment: This works :) Thanks a lot. Actually I can just add the border specifying the grid row and column, without having to include the TextBlock within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  style with trigger and put the style either in windows resources or app resources depending upon scope you want

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="NotCalledBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource NotCalledBorder}" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="test1" Grid.Row="0" OpacityMask="Black">
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="test2" Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>
        <Border Style="{StaticResource NotCalledBorder}" Grid.Row="2">
            <TextBlock Text="test3" Grid.Row="2" OpacityMask="Black"></TextBlock>
         </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="test4" Grid.Row="3"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[Conditional style in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340982/conditional-style-in-wpf). Adding border to two textblocks only. You can apply style and add to as many as you want

Comment: I'm sorry. When I said selected blocks - I meant "selected few". Not selection. I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Basic will be same only different is style scope it can be textbox.style also

Comment: The style works. But the border is added to the very first textblock in the xaml no matter where I add the border. It is only added to the first textblock.