# Dynamic Style Binding with IValueConverter

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I am trying to set a style, which is defined in the `App.xaml`, dynamically when loading a user control and it's just not applying the style for some reason (i.e. there is no error occurring, it's just not applying the style).

I'm sure it's because I've defined the binding wrong, but I'm unable to figure out what I need to do differently to get it to work.

## App.xaml Style

The style I'm after is the `RunningTitleBlock` and it's comprised of a couple other styles that I've included in the below code sample.

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}"
       x:Key="HeaderBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HeaderBlock}"
       x:Key="TitleBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Label"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TitleBlock}"
       x:Key="RunningTitleBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.0, 0.5"
                                 EndPoint="1.0, 0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1.0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

## Binding on the user control

I'm trying to get the `Binding` to bind to a value returned from a value converter.

```
Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey={Binding Path=MonitoringType, Converter={StaticResource TSConverter}}}"
```

## Code

### MonitoringTypes Enum

```
public enum MonitoringTypes
{
    Running,
    Failed,
    Paused,
    Favorites,
}
```

### User Control

Here what I'm trying to do is concatenate the string value of the `MonitoringTypes` enum value that's passed in with some well known text to build a style name that exists in the `App.xaml`. The value converter is being called ***and*** returning the correct value, but for some reason the style isn't applying.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MonitorWorkflow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MonitorWorkflow : UserControl
{
    public MonitorWorkflow(MonitoringTypes monitoringType)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MonitorWorkflowViewModel { MonitoringType = monitoringType };
    }
}

public class MonitorWorkflowViewModel
{
    public MonitoringTypes MonitoringType { get; set; }
}

public class TitleStyleValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = (MonitoringTypes)value;
        return string.Format("{0}TitleBlock", Enum.GetName(typeof(MonitoringTypes), type));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.Parse(typeof(MonitoringTypes), value.ToString().Substring(0, value.ToString().IndexOf("TitleBlock")));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably just use an IValueConverter and return the style.

Comment: The property that you bind to needs to be a dependency property or you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify the bindings when the value updates.  In your case, you would need to notify that your "TitleBlockStyle" property has changed whenever your enum value changes (wrap it in a property).  You are probably best off using a ValueConverter instead and bind it to your enum like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082509/use-a-styleselector-for-a-button

Comment: @patrickinmpls, I've updated my question to show where I've attempted to use a value converter.

Comment: @Moozhe, I've updated my question to show where I've attempted to use a value converter.

Comment: @code4life, so you're wanting to see if just the `Background` gets applied if I don't try to inherit?

Comment: Oops, I speed-read the post and skipped a couple important points. Sorry about that. Will repost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to skip the `DynamicResource` statement and using the `Converter` provide the `Style` directly.

```
Style="{Binding Path=MonitoringType, Converter={StaticResource TSConverter}}"
```

In `TSConverter`, you can return a `Style` rather than a string. Kind of like this:

```
public class TitleStyleValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = (MonitoringTypes)value;
        var styleToReturn = FindResource(
            string.Format("{0}TitleBlock", 
                Enum.GetName(typeof(MonitoringTypes), type)));
        if (styleToReturn != null)
            return (Style)styleToReturn;
        else 
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // not sure if you need this anymore... 
        return Enum.Parse(typeof(MonitoringTypes), value.ToString().Substring(0,
           value.ToString().IndexOf("TitleBlock")));
    }
}
```

---

This is what I did but with the following code instead. I actually just answered my own question while you answered it as well. Good timing!

```
public class TitleStyleValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var type = (MonitoringTypes)value;
        return App.Current.Resources[string.Format("{0}TitleBlock", Enum.GetName(typeof(MonitoringTypes), type))];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Enum.Parse(typeof(MonitoringTypes), value.ToString().Substring(0, value.ToString().IndexOf("TitleBlock")));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mike, I've thought a bit more about your code, and wonder if you might want to look at `DataTriggers` to enforce the style rather than this approach. This is how I've been doing it for the sort of styling approach you're undertaking.

Comment: I think you're right - that is a lot more concise. I can build one style, do a simple `StaticResource` binding on the `Style` for the `Label` and then use the `DataTrigger` to switch up the style.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Style DayModeButton = null; 

void loadStyle() 
{
Uri uri1 = new Uri("/Resources/ButtonStyle.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                ResourceDictionary resDict1 = Application.LoadComponent(uri1) as ResourceDictionary;

foreach (object obj in resDict1.Values) //Set explicit reference
     if (obj is Style) DayModeButton = (Style)obj;
}



[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(Style))]
public class GetStyleConverter: IValueConverter
{
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
               return DayModeButton ; 
         }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
         {
             return 0;
         }
}
```

Comment: maybe a comment or something to explain your code :)