# Adding Behavior or Style Based on DataContext Type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, caliburn.micro

I need to apply Behavior/Style based on type of the DataContext/Binding of an element and not on the type of FrameworkElement itself -

What I'm searching for is some equivalent of -

```
<Style TargetType={typeof(DataContext) is SomeSelectableType}>
    <Setter Property="cal:Message.Attach" Value="[Event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown]=[Action OnSelect]"/>
</Style>
```

OR

```
<Style TargetType={typeof(DataContext) is SelectableObject}>
    <DataTrigger Binding="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style>
```

Comment: Only thing I could think of in this case would be a way of setting the DataTemplate via a DataTemplateSelector for which you could trap the datacontext "type" based on known types in your project.  It would also involve the use of a converter at which point you could say return this style. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060761/dynamic-style-binding-with-ivalueconverter   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18777/Routed-Template-Selection-in-WPF  would involve both of those.  TargetType could also be determined programmatically but not common.

Comment: Is there a lot of custom behaviour/styling that you wish to apply? I it sounds like this could be the perfect opportunity to use multiple views based on the various types you're binding to; this may be overkill if you're just after a few simple properties. I can throw an example in the answers if that sounds like something that might be useful.

Comment: @Chris: It would certainly help to see your example. Thanks. I have also updated my question to better explain what I was trying.

Answer (score 4):

You could apply the style based on the FrameworkElement, but restrict the triggers based on the type of the DataContext.

Then in your triggers you can set the appropriate properties depending on the type.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button IsEnabled="False">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Style.Triggers>

                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InstanceTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="ViewModel1"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InstanceTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="ViewModel2"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InstanceTypeConverter}}" Value="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}"></Condition>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False"></Condition>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="ViewModel2 And Not Enabled"></Setter>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Convert instance to its type

```
public  class InstanceTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value !=null ? value.GetType() : null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There should arguably be a null check on the Convert return statement, and helpfully in newer C# versions you can do it shorthand: return value?.GetType();