# Set specific style on user control based on custom DP

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, dependency-properties

Here is my problem statement and partial solution which I could come up with. Need help trying to close this to a final elegant solution.

I have a user control which has a few custom Dependency Properties. One of them is ButtonStyle. My user control essentially just contains a button. Sample snippet code is as below.

The button in the usercontrol can have only 2 styles - each one fundamentally different from other (colors, foreground, background etc) based on the style passed when the user control is called.

The style will also need to contain DataTrigger as part of the design.

How would my XAML look like leveraging this custom DP property and supporting 2 styles on the button.

Any sample code/links/pointers - will really appreciate

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Custom DP Code

```
public partial class ButtonUserControl : UserControl
{
    #region ButtonStyle DP
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonStyle", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string ButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonStyleProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

   #region ButtonContent DP
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public string ButtonContent
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    public ButtonUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var mw_vm = new ButtonUserControlViewModel();
        DataContext = mw_vm;
    }
}
```

Comment: You already mention you use a datatrigger. Do you mean that using somthing like <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ButtonStyle}" Value="Something"> does not work for you?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082509/use-a-styleselector-for-a-button) is quite similar, check it out.