# How to change the style property from the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

How can I modify the Style property from the ViewModel? I am using WPF and MVVM with Caliburn Micro. I have two diferents styles for the buttons, and I want to change it from the ViewModel when the user clicked the button.

I'm trying to use this in my xaml:

```
<Button 
      Style="{Binding Path=StyleButton, Mode=OneWay}" 
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="1"
      Content="News" 
      x:Name="LoadFirstPage" />
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. I hope it helps

Comment: You don't change the style from a view model. If you do this, you don't need a view model in the first place. You may set the `Style` in the view based on a value of some view model property though using a [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082509/use-a-styleselector-for-a-button) though.

Answer (score 5):

Putting view related types like `Style` in view models violates MVVM principles. Instead, expose a property that represents the state of the button that determines whether one style or the other should be displayed.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private bool _isPageLoaded;
   public bool IsPageLoaded
   {
      get => _isPageLoaded;
      set
      {
         if (_isPageLoaded == value)
            return;

         _isPageLoaded = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
   {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }

   // ...other properties and methods.
}
```

Be sure ot give it a meaningful name. It does not have to be of type `bool`, but it fits here. Also be sure to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to reflect changes to the property in the user interface.

Set this property to the right value in the command or method that is called when your button is clicked. From here, there are multiple options for your scenario.

### Style Trigger Solution

Instead of exchanging the style altogether, you could create a common style for both states with a trigger that sets properties differently according to the state stored in the property.

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
   <!-- Properties set for IsPageLoaded=False -->
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPageLoaded}" Value="True">
         <!-- Properties set for IsPageLoaded=True -->
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="News" 
        x:Name="LoadFirstPage"/>
```

### Value Converter Solution

You can create a value converter that returns the style that corresponds to the property state.

```
public class ConditionToStyleConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public Style SuccessStyle { get; set; }

   public Style FailureStyle { get; set; }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (bool)value ? SuccessStyle : FailureStyle;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Here is an example of two styles and a converter that you put in a resource dictionary in scope.

```
<Style x:Key="MyFirstButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MySecondButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>

<local:ConditionToStyleConverter x:Key="ConditionToStyleConverter"
                                 SuccessStyle="{StaticResource MyFirstButtonStyle}"
                                 FailureStyle="{StaticResource MySecondButtonStyle}"/>
```

You would use the converter on your button like this.

```
<Button Style="{Binding IsPageLoaded, Converter={StaticResource ConditionToStyleConverter}}"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Content="News" 
        x:Name="LoadFirstPage"/>
```

In this example the converter is a simple `IValueConverter` that exposes properties for the style, so for different styles you would have to create other instances. It is also possible to create a multi-value converter that can bind styles directly, but for your scenario as a beginner, this solution should be enough.

Comment: I dont know why, but when i use your Style Tigger Solution and I change the IsPageLoaded property, the contentcontrol that there is in my project dont load the content. Exactly this code `ActivateItem(new PostsViewModel());` this does not work, but your solution is fantastic, thank you so much.

Comment: @NicolasHL The style should not cause any side-effects like this, but it is hard to tell why it seems to affect a `ContentControl` without code. How does the `ContentControl` know about the `IsPageLoaded` property that was not there before?

Comment: this is the part of code that execute when the button is clicked.
`public void LoadFirstPage()
        {
            ActivateItem(new PostsViewModel());

            IsPageLoaded = true;
        }
`
I don't know if the code is correct, but this is the form how your solution work for me.

Comment: The Style Trigger Solution works for me, Thanks