# Detect button down/up event with C# in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am learning to program Windows Phone app with C# and XAML. However I am having problem detecting the button down/up events.

My XAML code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Class="Tally2.MainPage"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeHuge}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Row 0: The Header -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="24,24,0,12">
            <TextBlock Text="tap to count" Margin="-3,-8,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- Row 1: The text block containing the count -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="CountTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Text="0" Height="259" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

        <!-- Row 2: The reset button -->
        <Button x:Name="buttonMain" MouseLeftButtonDown="buttonMain_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="buttonMain_MouseLeftButtonUp" Grid.Row="1" Margin="74,240,84,117">
            <Button.Content>
                <Image x:Name="theImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/green.png"/>
        </Button.Content>
            </Button>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

and the C# code

```
    private void buttonMain_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/red.png", UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        theImage.Source = imgSource;
        theImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    }

    private void buttonMain_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/green.png", UriKind.Relative);
        BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        theImage.Source = imgSource;
        theImage.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    }
```

What happen is the image green.png is not loaded on start up. When the app is running and I clicked on the button red.png is loaded but it's stretched until outside the button's border.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Click events rather than mouse down. There is no mouse on the phone.

```xml
<Button x:Name="buttonMain" Click="buttonMain_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Row="1" Margin="74,240,84,117">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image x:Name="theImage" Stretch="Uniform" Source="/Images/green.png"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: I can detect click but, how do you change the button image when it's pressed and released with click events?

Comment: Ah, that! You actually need to change the button template. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863799/how-to-change-button-template-dynamically-wpf

Comment: So is there no way to use events to detect those via code, instead I must use button template? I am not familiar with template. :( 

OK will check the link. Just wish that there's a simpler way.

Comment: Not that I know of. Basically there are several states of a button. You edit them using expression Blend, then Blend generates XAML based on the states that you modify (in Blend). Then your button uses the custom templates for its actions. Search google for "blend modify button state wpf tutorial".

Comment: For changing templates, I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476963/windows-phone-7-wp7-change-a-buttons-background-color-on-click)